# Laravel Route Filter not Updating Response

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am using the [lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel) package for OAuth in my API (a Laravel 4.1.* app) and it provides a filter to easily verify authorization before running a route like this:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api', 'before' => 'oauth:auth'), function() {
   // My API Routes
});
```

It returns a JSON response that doesn't follow the format I am using in my API and would like to change it to be consistent. So I created a filter in *filters.php* and set it to run as an **after** filter.

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'core', 'before' => 'oauth:auth', 'after' => 'oauth.cleanresponse'), function() {
   // My API Routes
)};
```

And the filter:

```
/**
* OAuth Package returns JSON response in custom format that is not consistent with
* Core API output. We need to alter the output to fit the standard response.
*/
Route::filter('oauth.cleanresponse', function($request, $response) {

   if ($response instanceof Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse)
   {
      $responseData = $response->getData();
      if (isset($responseData->error_message));
      {
        $newResponse = new API\ApiResponse();
        $newResponse->setError($responseData->error_message);
        $newResponse->setCode($responseData->status);
        return Response::json($newResponse->error(), $responseData->status);      
      }
   }

   });
```

The filter runs fine, and I can `var_dump()` out my changes just before returning them.

But the value returned from the API call in the response is not my new value, it's still the original value created in the **before** filter by the oauth library.

TL;DR; Why does the response from an **after** filter not override the response from a **before** filter and how can I work around this issue?

**NOTE:** I do not want to edit the OAuth package because then anytime I do a `composer update` it might overwrite my changes.

### EDIT

A closer inspection of the Laravel router (*Illuminate/Routing/Router.php*) has this:

```
/**
 * Dispatch the request to a route and return the response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return mixed
 */
public function dispatchToRoute(Request $request)
{
    $route = $this->findRoute($request);

    $this->events->fire('router.matched', array($route, $request));

    // Once we have successfully matched the incoming request to a given route we
    // can call the before filters on that route. This works similar to global
    // filters in that if a response is returned we will not call the route.
    $response = $this->callRouteBefore($route, $request);

    if (is_null($response))
    {
        $response = $route->run($request);
    }

    $response = $this->prepareResponse($request, $response);

    // After we have a prepared response from the route or filter we will call to
    // the "after" filters to do any last minute processing on this request or
    // response object before the response is returned back to the consumer.
    $this->callRouteAfter($route, $request, $response);

    return $response;
}
```

It appears to block dispatching a request if the **before** filter returns a result and then it calls the **after** filter. The problem is it doesn't capture the response! It seems that this:

```
$this->callRouteAfter($route, $request, $response);
```

Should be something like this (although this specifically doesn't work):

```
$response = $this->callRouteAfter($route, $request, $response);
```

Can anyone think of a way around this?

Comment: I almost sent a pull request to laravel/framework before I found your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the response in the current instance using

```
$json = 'prepare the json here';
// set and return response with new data
return $response->setContent($json);
```

Comment: "In the current instance" -- meaning what?

Comment: Received as argument in the `function($request, $response)`.

Comment: It's a copy of the value (i.e. not passed by reference). That doesn't work.

Comment: `setCOntent()` method used for setting new content in the response, did you try it ? Not sure tho, because of another `API` you are using, so give it a try and if doesn't work then I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @cillosis `setContent()` works because objects are passed (and assigned) by reference in PHP 5.

Answer (score 0):

"After" filters have 3 parameters and not 2: route, request and response ("before" filters only have 2: route and request, because there is no response at that stage).

In your code, your after filter function has only two parameters, so your `$request` contains a `Route`, and your `$response` contains a Request. You need to add `$route` as first parameter.

After that, you can then call `$response->header()` and `$response->setContent()` to modify the generated response.

"After" filters cannot return a new `$response`, they can only modify the one passed to them.

Sample working code:

```
Route::filter('api_headers', function($route, $request, $response) {
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    $response->header('P3P', 'CP="IDC DSP COR CURa ADMa OUR IND PHY ONL COM STA"');
});
Route::group(array('prefix'=>'api', 'after'=>'api_headers'), function()
{
    // ...
});
```